# Query for join in Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I want to write a join like

```
Select a.id,a.desc,b.desc from A a  left join B b on a.MEDIA_ID = b.ID
```

I have create two Entities A & B and created `CrudRepository<A,Long>`.

Now, in the crudRepository in need to write a method which can get the data using the above join.

Also, i created a transient variable in entity A (Names it as 'bDescription)
how to achieve this in *Spring Data JPA*.

Note: I need join just to find out 'description'(a column in B) for a particular id(primary key in B and mapped as 'MEDIA_ID' in A) of Entity B..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't forget to mark your choosed answer as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a sample of JOIN query with SpringData

```
public final static String FIND_WITH_DESC_QUERY = "SELECT a,b.desc as  bDescription " + 
                                                   "FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.descriptions b " +
                                                   "WHERE a.mediaID = :id";


@Query(FIND_WITH_DESC_QUERY)
public List<Media> findWithDescription(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Note :

- `descriptions` is the mapping of the relationship between entities A and B.
- this assume `@OneToMany Set<B> descriptions()`

[useful link](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-data-jpa-repository.html)

Comment: Thanks Ben. I want to implement in other way. Table B has a id which i want to keep in where condition, Like "SELECT a,C.Description as cDescription FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.descriptions c where R.media_Id = c.id"; when i did that it's not working, during starting of server it throwing up a mapping exception which say 'A is not mapped'

Comment: Do you have @Entity annotation on class A ? (to provide more info about your use case : edit the question please)

Comment: Yes it's there . When i run the server it throwing me Mapping error.

Comment: be sure to use the class name in your query and not the table name (if they are different)

Comment: For Reletionship between entities i given it as @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn( name="Description")
    Set<CacheMedia> cacheMedia; and in repository my query looks like 'SELECT A,C.Description FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.cacheMedia C where R.media_Id = C.id'. still i am not getting the result instead i got BadGrammer Exception.